# Getting Error in Makefile while compressing folder

Tags: makefile, tar

I have a folder demo and inside that I have made a Makefile and various other files. Now I want to zip this folder for that I have written the following Makefile but it is always giving me error

Makefile-:

```
all:demo.tgz

demo.tgz:
    cd ..
    tar -cvzf demo.tgz demo/
```

error is "demo no file or directory"

can i anyone tell me what is wrong here.....

it is giving me the following error

```
jatinkhurana@jatinkhurana-HP-ProBook-4430s:~/Mtech1/SoftwareLab/makefile/demo$ make
cd ..
tar -cvzf demo.tgz demo/
tar: demo: Cannot stat: No such file or directory
tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors
make: *** [demo.tgz] Error 2
```

Comment: Does this makefile live at the same location as the demo directory?

Comment: yes ... it is inside the demo directory....

Comment: So that's a "no" to my question then. Given your answer though can you figure out the problem? Why would `tar` be telling you that `demo` doesn't exist when you run it there?

Comment: I have shown the error in the question now.... i am not getting why it's giving the error

Comment: What directory are you in when you are running that? What directory are you asking tar to archive? What path are you giving it? What happens if you run `ls demo` from that same directory?

Comment: when i run the make , I am in the demo directory as shown in the error dialog above...... ls demo is listing the demo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
all:demo.tgz

demo.tgz:
    ( \
    cd .. ; \
    tar -cvzf demo.tgz demo/ ;\
    )
```

Each line in a recipe will run in own environment. Changing the directory with `cd` will not change the environment for the next line of you recipe.

Simple pack your commands into braces an add `;\` at the end of each line. This will make it ONE command which runs in one shell environment.

Comment: You don't need the parentheses.  Each recipe line in make is run in it's own shell, so any `cd` you do is automatically undone.  Just `cd .. && tar -cvzf demo.tgz demo` is good enough.

Answer (score 2):

Each line in a make file is run in a separate environment. This means that the `cd ..` doesn't change the current dir for the following commands. You have to force the commands to run in the same env by combining them.

```
demo.tgz:
    cd .. && tar -cvzf demo.tgz demo/
```

Comment: I don't know about this... but if it is right... then I would surely get the error

Comment: well try it... The error you get is `demo` doesn't exists. That's because you are still inside `demo`.

Comment: problem is solved... you were right... each command run in the different environment......